# Unknown error when trying to 'upsert' with ArcGIS API for Python

Tags: python, arcgis

I am trying to perform an 'upsert' (update + insert) operation on a feature layer via ArcGIS API for Python. My input data is a geojson file that gets uploaded as per the available [guides](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/appending-features/#add-the-source-csv-item-to-the-gis):

```
data_item = gis.content.add(
    item_properties={
        'title': 'My Data File',
        'type': 'GeoJson',  
        'overwrite': True,
    },
    data="myfile.geojson"
)
```

Then I attempt the append operation:

```
my_layer.append(
    item_id=data_item.id,
    upload_format='geojson', 
    upsert=True,
    upsert_matching_field='an_unique_field',
    update_geometry=True,
)
```

This returns `Exception: Unknown Error (Error Code: 500)`. The geojson file is valid (checked in geojson.io). Attempts with a smaller file (original has ~4000 polygons) or appending a featureCollection instead of geojson fail with the same error. Manually updating the data via ArcGIS online works fine with the exact same file. Any leads here?

I have succesfully performed the operation using [`edit_features()`](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#arcgis.features.FeatureLayer.edit_features) instead of [`append()`](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.features.toc.html#arcgis.features.FeatureLayer.append) but it requires querying the layer, mapping OBJECTIDs to `an_unique_field`, creating separate `adds` and `updates` collections, then splitting the collections into 250 features chunks. I'd like to skip all this with a single `append` call if possible.

Comment: right, but what would that be for a geojson file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be due to missing values in the `upsert_matching_field`. I had missing values in other properties (which are configured to allow null values) too. Correcting those got rid of the `unknown error`, but the function would still fail to complete (it ran for 2 hours then errored out with a permission denied message).

Kind of silly, but this could be better documented and the error should be more informative. I assumed the method would skip blank/falsy values. The part about `source_table_name` being required also seems to be a documentation flaw.